# Elegant way to handle queuing up multiple tasks into single bulkadd/batch

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I use task queue quite extensively in an application.
Most of the time it's using the following pattern:

```py
yield (add_foo_task_async(), add_bar_task_async(), add_baz_task_async())

# add_foo_task_async() etc are defined like this
    @classmethod
    @ndb.tasklet
    def add_foo_task_async(cls, param):
        queue = taskqueue.Queue("foo")
        # perform various modifications on params etc...
        params = {
            "param": param,

        }
        task = taskqueue.Task(url=uri_for("tasks/foo_worker"), params=params)
        result = yield queue.add_async(task)
        raise ndb.Return(result)
```

**The problem is it seems to create a "ladder" of "bulkAdds".**

[image: ladder of bulk adds]

I'd like to improve the performance so that there aren't all these ladders.

One solution I'm considering is creating a class where the tasks are created and stored in a list. The class would also have "add_tasks_to_taskqueue" method which queues them all to the actual task queue. One issue however is that the quite a lot of tasks that I use are queued up in _post_put_hook (so I'd need a way to pass this class everywhere). Another concern is that I use multiple queues at the moment, so I assume I'll need to change that?

**update**
I've seen that ndb context has some auto-batching code for memcache and urlfetch. Could the proposed solution somehow use a similar method where we extend ndb context (is that possible?) and use something like get_contenxt().add_task_to_batch_queue(task)

**Is there a better/elegant way to handle what I'm trying to achieve?**

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that we can help you.  You understand that you need to batch your tasks.  How to do that depends on the details of your code which is probably too much detail for a StackOverflow question....

Comment: @gaefan see edit regarding somehow using ndb context. Could one extend ndb context and use that context with some auto-batching logic?